# Completable future java 8 understanding the point of application

Tags: java-8

I am trying to refactor a java 8 code for better readability and also being able to debug a code. I have a function that returns CompletionStage of a Map with key as String and value as someItem .

```
 return response.thenApplyAsync(
        r -> {
            Map<String, someItem> result = new HashMap<>();

            // The result can be null
            if (r != null) {
                result = r.getItemList().stream().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                        x -> x.getFirstBlock().getSomevalue(), Function.identity(),
                        // check and warn for duplicates
                        (p1, p2) -> {
                            LOGGER.warn(String.format("duplicate some value found: %s",
                                    p1.getFirstBlock().getSomevalue()));

                            return p1;
                        })
                );
            }
            return result;
        }
    );
```

I refactored the code as :

```
try {
        someItem1 respVal=response.toCompletableFuture().get();

        List<someItem> itmLst=respVal.getItemList();


        Map<String, someItem> result=new HashMap<String, someItem>();

        for(someItem itm:itmLst){
            if(result.containsKey(itm.getFirstBlock().getSomevalue())){
                LOGGER.warn(String.format("duplicate some value found: %s",itm.getFirstBlock().getSomevalue()));
            }else{
                result.put(itm.getFirstBlock().getSomevalue(),itm);
            }

        }

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);

    } catch (InterruptedException|ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return null;
```

i am really not sure that by making the above refactoring what would be the impact. To be precise, i need to know that whether using a CompletableFuture to only the end result is exactly the same as using the whole CompletableFuture with apply async or so. Form documentation by oracle, i understand that the apply async is only meant to use the current execution stage's default asynchrounous execution facility but does it apply equally while asking for a completedFuture for a value. Any help is highly appreciated.
Please note the try catch is just a part of exception handling here for my methods which i haven't shown.

Comment: `thenApplyAsync` is chaining a dependent operation without executing it. Calling `get()` means *waiting*  until the computation has finished and get the result, followed by an immediate execution of the subsequent code. How can this be the same?

Comment: @Holger I am concerned more about the total overall outcome. Is it a good practice to use completedFuture instead of applying a then combine/apply async. Currently my execution time is not affected by using one or the other. What i wonder is that by making the code more debuggable/readable and then applying a completed future is a good practice over the original factoring of the code. Please suggest.

Comment: So you mean, *besides* the fact that it defeats the actual purpose of chaining an operation to  a possibly async operation? Well, if that’s what you want, there is nothing wrong with that. But when all you want to get, is more debuggable/readable code, there is no need to change the application logic. Just put the contents of the lambda expression into a new method and use `thenApplyAsync` with a method reference…